# Simple SQL syntax error in fetchRow() Zend Framework

Tags: mysql, zend-framework, syntax, row, fetch

i got a simple instruction like this:

```
    $db = Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter();
$select = $db->select();
$select
        ->from(array("b" => "barcos"))
        ->join(array("i" => "imagens"), 'b.id = i.barcoId')
        ->where("b.id = {$idEmbarcacao}")
        ->group("i.barcoId");

$this->view->anuncio = $db->fetchRow($select);
```

and it returns this error

```
Message: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1
```

it is driving me crazy, because only in this particular page it returns this error, in some other pages it is fine. My database is correctly populated. it shoud return something but a error. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Fernando, could you print the final SQL your ZF_Db is creating?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this way

```
$db = Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter();
$select = $db->select();
$select
        ->from(array("b" => "barcos"))
        ->join(array("i" => "imagens"), 'b.id = i.barcoId')
       // ->where("b.id = {$idEmbarcacao}")
        ->where("b.id = ?", $idEmbarcacao)
        ->group("i.barcoId");

$this->view->anuncio = $db->fetchRow($select);
```

you can use `->where("b.id = ?", $idEmbarcacao)` instead of `->where("b.id = {$idEmbarcacao}")`